# Api to get list of extensions installed in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, safari, safari-extension

I am developing an extension for chrome and safari.One step in this app is  to get all the already installed extensions.Is there any safari or chrome api that can give the list of installed extensions? In safari installed extensions are stored in `~/Library/Safari/Extensions/Extensions.plist` but i am not able to find any related api.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management

Comment: @WolfWar: i am really thankful. Do you know same for safari?

Comment: no, I'm not familiar with Safari development or documentation, but it should be something similar

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72544362/6666348

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### For Chrome:

From within a Chrome Extension, you can use [`chrome.management.getAll`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-getAll) to obtain a list of the installed extensions and apps.

#### For Safari:

There is no public API to do this in Safari, whether from a webpage or from within a Safari Extension.

However, you can code your Safari Extension such that you can [detect whether *your* Safari extension is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046524/detect-if-safari-extension-is-installed) from your website.