# How to list installed plugins & extensions in web browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, webbrowser-control, browserify

How to check extensions & plugins installed in client's browser?

I've tried chrome API, and also [chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions), but I wasn't able to get it...

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195395/api-to-get-list-of-extensions-installed-in-browser

Comment: chrome.management.getAll(function callback) not working, can u give sample code