# Extension manager APIs for Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

Is there any extension manager API available for Safari which is similar to chrome management of Google Chrome and AddonManager of Firefox so that we can get the info of extensions installed on Safari.

Answer (score 0):

No. This API is not publicly available in Safari.

Safari Extensions cannot:

- Install other extensions
- Uninstall themselves (or other extensions)
- See what other extensions are installed

However, you can code your Safari Extension such that you can [detect whether *your* Safari extension is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046524/detect-if-safari-extension-is-installed) from your website.